# ajax request for just a fragment of an html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm taking the [jQuery The Return Flight](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-the-return-flight) course at codeschool and there's a lesson where there is this peculiar function they use on ajax.
The ajax function is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var el = $("#tour")
        el.on("click", "button", function() {
                $.ajax('/photos.html', {
                    data: {location: el.data('location')},
                    success: function(response) {
                         $('.photos').html(response).fadeIn();
                         }
                 });
        });
});
```

And this brings only one `<li></li>` item from an html file, thanks to the data parameter option of the `$.ajax` function. I understand everything here but one thing: I didn't know fragments of documents could be returned ie a section of the file or a div of a file, I thought only entire files could be requested with Ajax.

My confusion is, how does this function do to identify which `<li></li>` item it will bring if the list item has no identifier?:

```
<li>
  <img src="/assets/photos/paris1.jpg">
  <span style="display: none;">Arc de Triomphe</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="/assets/photos/paris2.jpg">
  <span style="display: none;">The Eiffel Tower</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="/assets/photos/london.jpg">
  <span style="display: none;">London</span>
</li>
```

I'm really confused at this point, and I would like to see if someone can explain how bringing a fraction of a document as an ajax request be achievable.

Comment: This is done with server-end, they probably use a database so they return from the database the img where the location matches, its certainly not  big file of images, its generated html, they probably just save in database the url and name of the img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data parameter has no effect on the client-side. It is simply sent along with the request to the server, where the server can use it to determine an appropriate response. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

That being said, jQuery does provide a utility for loading a fragment from an ajax request, though behind the scenes its still making the complete request, and just parsing the results.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Comment: Actually load() brings in the entire content of the requested page but includes the methodology to parse that page for the selector in question. Try it while viewing the request / response in your browser's console. EDIT: I see that you said that, it was "loading a fragment" that threw me off.